# Screen corruption after wake - 10.13.5, 13-inch Early 2011 MPB

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, sleep-wake

Ever since the macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 Update on my 13-inch, Early 2011, this issue has been happening recurrently:

1. The computer goes to sleep (or I activate sleep manually)
2. Some time passes, 10, 20 min
3. I wake the computer and the screen can already present corrupted graphics, or I login and some apps start showing corrupted graphics.

The computer gets slower when this happens and I have noticed that if I try to click through the apps, and restart some of them, everything comes back to normal.

This never happened before the update and I started noticing this behaviour the day after the software update.

I have seen some people with similar issues in other posts, but it seemed that the only way they found to fix it was to update the OS to a new version, but in this case, the computer is already on the last High Sierra version.

Also, some have pointed out Metal as a possible culprit, as it seems there is an ongoing migration of the OS to use Metal. Could this be the problem?

Thank for any help you might lend, would be really appreciated.

Comment: “Corrupted Graphics” Can you add pictures? Does it show in screenshots?

Comment: I dont have one, but I will take a screenshot/picture the next time it happens